# How to save data from listview to a text file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

So I know this has been asked, but I'm kinda struggling with it. I have a basic windows forms program that stores 4 values to an array, and then display it in a list-view. but now I have a extra button that if I click on it, I just want it to save the stored values and export it to a text file. 
And will it be easier to just export it directly from the array? And how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of the application? WinForms/WPF/WebForms? Add more tags to reflect context

Comment: Array of what? Opening a StreamWriter and just looping through the array is probably going to be the easiest.

Comment: sorry, it is a WinForms application and its an array of string

Comment: Hey guys I got it righ! thanks a lot for your time and help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, array, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Error 2 Unrecognized escape sequence i got this error when i entered the path?

Comment: Try preceding the path with a @, as in @"C:\Documents\File.txt"

Comment: add @ at the start of the path string

Comment: Ok I did that, but it gives an error when it runs and says that access is denied, and the file isn't set to read only. Sorry guys i am really a Noob with this.

Comment: @JohnathanSalmon: It's because VS doesn't have rights to write in this file. Make sure the file is not located in a folder where admin rights are required (try writing in a new file in your `Documents` folder).

Answer (score 1):

```
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\listViewContent.txt")) {
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items) {
        tw.WriteLine(item.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code works good, but it only displays the first column's value, which is just the name. how can i make it show the other 3 columns?

Comment: What are the 3 others columns? Is your `listView` `View` property set to `Details`?

Comment: Yes it is set to Detail, The first Column is Name (followed by), Surname, Age, Meeting Type

Comment: How do you populate your `listView`? Do you use the `Item.Tag` property?

Answer (score 1):

Just incase someone still needs it, this is just a thorough version @othiel answer with subitems

```
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\listViewContent.txt"))
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(item.Text);
                    for (int a = 1; a <= 3; a++ ) //the 3 = number of subitems in a listview 
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[a].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            MessageBox.Show("TEXT FILE NOT FOUND");
        }
```

Just make sure to set the listView1 in details.

Answer (score 0):

And now, with fancy save file dialog! :)

```
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "DumpFile1"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text files (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Save document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            File.WriteAllLines(filename, array, Encoding.UTF8); //array is your array of strings
        }
    }
```

You need to **add a reference** to **PresentationFramework**. (Right click on *References* in *Solution Explorer* -> *Add Reference*, in *.NET* tab select *PresentationFramework*)